# Call a factory_boy super class method in a ~Factory sub-class without `self`

Tags: python, inheritance, factory-boy

Is there a way to call a parent factory's method from a subclass?

The usual `super(ThisClass, self)` or `ParentClass.method(self)` methods don't work, because `self` isn't an instance of the class, it is the object that the factory returns.

```
class SomethingFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    # Meta, fields, etc

    @factory.post_generation
    def post(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        # Some steps


class SomethingElseFactory(SomethingFactory):

    @factory.post_generation
    def post(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        super(SomethingElseFactory, self).post(create, extracted, **kwargs)
```

The error is `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`.

(The shortcut `super().post(create, extracted, kwargs)` generates the same error.)

How can I access that parent factory `SomethingFactory.post` method from the sub-class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do in the base class `post()` can you pull it out into a function and call it from both places:

```
def set_attributes(obj):
    obj.attr1 = True
    obj.attr2 = 1000


class SomethingFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    # Meta, fields, etc

    @factory.post_generation
    def post(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        set_attributes(self)


class SomethingElseFactory(SomethingFactory):

    @factory.post_generation
    def post(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        set_attributes(self)
        # Do some other stuff
```